# Does Vanilla (non-Bukkit) servers have a limit on mobs spawning? If so, how do I remove it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a modded server (with the FTB Crash Landing modpack), running Vanilla Server software (the one where you download from [minecraft.net](http://www.minecraft.net) and then add all your mods in etc.

However, something seems to be wrong with it. I'm not getting as many mobs as I usually would when playing Single Player. On my Single-player world, I would get at least 300+ mobs in my world at any one time in the night. However... When I play on my Multiplayer Server, I only get barely 100 mobs at any one time.

EDIT: 3 players over single-player LAN still gives at least 300+ mobs, and we're all in the same area (the starting spaceship). Even with **ONLY 1** player on the multi-player hosted server, it only has 100 mobs.

**Is there some sort of limit that limits the number of mobs that can spawn at any one time?**
If so, **Is there any way to increase that limit, or get rid of it altogether?**

---

My computer runs Windows 8.1 with 4GB memory and an Intel i5 Processor that has Intel Graphics attached to it.
The server I bought (rented) has 8GB memory and uses Intel Xeon E3-1240v2 Processors. ([Link to Server Provider](http://vortexservers.com))

---

> @MrLemon, I've just tested it with the exact same server setup (in terms of programs), but on my own computer.. It spawned 200+ mobs.
>   [Does Vanilla (non-Bukkit) servers have a limit on mobs spawning? If so, how do I remove it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190365/does-vanilla-non-bukkit-servers-have-a-limit-on-mobs-spawning-if-so-how-do-i/190692?noredirect=1#comment258287_190365)

So, I've managed to get it to spawn more than 70 mobs locally, but how do I do this on my remote server? (Remember, the programs; installation that are used are EXACTLY the same)

Comment: **Before anyone asks:** How many people plays on it? `3.`

Comment: By LAN, do you mean "open to LAN"? If so, try running the server.jar on your machine and connect to it with your client. Normally, the hostile mob cap is 70*(# Loaded Chunks)/256, which comes out to 79 in Singleplayer (17*17 chunks). The modpack definitely overrides this limit. I guess your server.jar lacks this setting, thus the cap is still active.

Comment: I'll give that a go.

Comment: @MrLemon, I've just tested it with the exact same server setup (in terms of programs), but on my own computer.. It spawned 200+ mobs.

Answer (score 1):

Mob caps are directly proportional to the total number of chunks eligible for spawning. To calculate the cap, the spawning area is expanded by one chunk in every direction (so the default gives 17×17 chunks), then the total number of chunks is plugged into the following formula:

cap = constant * chunks / 256

Each mob category has a separate cap and a different constant in the formula:

Hostile = 70
 Passive = 10
 Ambient (Bats) = 15
 Water = 5

So the most hostile monsters you can have is 70 and then no more mobs will spawn.

In multiplayer, chunks that are in range of multiple players are only counted once. So the more spread out the players are, the more chunks will be covered and the higher the caps will be.

Comment: It still doesn't answer how the modpack removes the limit in Single-player... And how this can be achieved in Multiplayer?

Comment: You can not edit the spawn limit of mobs it ONLY can be edited from the mods or the Minecraft's source code.

Comment: So there *is* a way. Can you state what mod? (Or change to the Source code?)

Comment: No dont know any mods that directly change the mob cap of Vanilla mobs but the mod dose configure the cap of the mobs from the mobs from the mod, i could change the source code i dont think i can redistribute it.

Comment: There is a SDK (source development kit) for Minecraft. Also, don't go trying to find the answer if you have close-to/no knowledge in programming. Also, to point out: The modpack uses CustomMobs; Vanilla mobs but buffed/regular/different-colored etc.

Comment: I dont want to start a fight here but for your knowing i have programming knowlage but i was trying to make it simple so the people with "close-to/no knowledge in programming"